# html5 audio generated by random audio file

Tags: php, html, html5-audio

I'm trying to make a simple page where it has a basic html5 audio player, but I want the player to be for a random audio file from a specific folder.

I've tried searching and researching but I came up with one script but it generates a blank page

Example:

```
<audio>
<?php

$dir = 'files/';
$scan = scandir($dir);  

for ($i = 0; $i<count($scan); $i++) {

    if ($scan[$i] != '.' && $scan[$i] != '..') {
        echo $scan[$i];
    }
}; 
?>
</audio>
```

I know about audio controls but I'm not worried about that right now.

Also if I ever get this solved I'm also trying to get  php and html5 audio to generate the id3 for the random audio file.

Comment: What's your problem? Is the problem that you don't get the randomness or is the audio not working?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the audio tag incorrectly. You need to have something like this:

```
<audio src="<?php #php code to echo file here ?>"></audio>
```

you put the URL of the file in the src attribute, not the content of the tag. Only some types of files work in different browsers. An OGG file format works in most browsers, but some need mp3. Make sure that you have the correct file format for it to work.

Comment: Just right before me :P

Comment: hate it when that happens :)

Comment: Also: Good to define the type of the data; type="audio/mpeg" etc.

Comment: Hehe ye, still up voting.

Comment: I know all of this lol I just put the audio brackets for example.

Comment: Then what are you asking for? We've given you a successful random generator for the files and auto extension finder and the correct way to do the audio.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried this myself and it works: (UPDATED)**

```
$dir = '../sound/'; // Change this so IT's true for your case.
$scan = scandir($dir);
$size = sizeof($scan);
$random = rand(1, $size);
$randomFile = $scan[$random];
$fileLocation = $dir. $randomFile;
```

Now you can get the extension of the file:

```
$explode = explode(".", $randomFile);
$extension = $explode[1];
```

**Full working code:**

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="<?php echo $fileLocation; ?>" type="audio/<?php echo $extension; ?>">
</audio>
```

Comment: How does it know what directory to look in or does this need to be in the same dire Tory as such audio files?

Comment: You just predefine what directory your files are in, it can whatever you want, OR you can have an array of folders and you can random generate from them like I did with random selection of files. Is this not what you were looking for?

Comment: Accept the answer and upvote it if it what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for I did what you said but got a white page. Could do piece it all together instead of segments?

Comment: It causes a 500 error

Comment: I updated my answer, it is using the audio controls correctly now. Make sure that you're pointing to a correct file/folder, so that $dir is true for your case.

Comment: Check my posts I updated it with what you said and I still get reformed out. There's nothing else on the page besides that code.

Comment: It won't let me edit but I did exactly as you put.

Comment: It won't let you edit what?

Comment: My original post. But I got it working. It seemed your code didn't close out in certain parts that's all.

Comment: if you are getting 500 errors and such you should enable error reporting in php.ini, as it will show you an error message describing the error instead of a 500 error.

Comment: What matters is if the answers are helpful or not.